# Why does switch(0) not result in a warning while if(0) does?

Tags: c, visual-studio-2012, gcc, clang

Given this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
    switch (0) { 
        case 1: printf("1"); 
        case 2: printf("2"); 
        default:
            printf("default");
            break; 
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I'd expect that the compiler would tell me something about either *conditional expression is constant* (`switch (0)` while VS2012 issues this warning for an `if(0)`) or *unreachable code* (`case 1`, `case 2`).

However, neither on [ideone](http://ideone.com/AsVPAk) nor on Visual Studio 2012 nor on recent GCCs I receive anything like that.

Why don't even decent compilers complain here?

Comment: Would you expect such a warning to catch a lot of bugs in real code?

Comment: @KerrekSB: well, since `if(0) ...;` results in a warning (*conditional expression is constant* on Visual Studio), I'd expect this here too

Comment: Did you compile with warnings enabled?  try `gcc -Wall -W -Werror`.

Comment: Unreachable code is not forbidden by the standard. I guess the compiler developers didn't bother.

Comment: I'd guess that the difference is in the frequency with which the warning might be useful.  It is quite common to constant `if` conditions; it is far less common to have constant `switch` values — verging on "I don't remember seeing one in the wild".  However, I can see it might conceivably be useful in some contexts — `switch (sizeof(somevar))` followed by code to handle different machine types (e.g. `case 2: …; break; case 4: …; break; case 8: …; break; default: assert(0); break;`).  I'm not sure that's good, but it might be valid.

Comment: @chqrlie I tried `gcc -Werror`. No warnings/errors

Comment: Does this warning appear when you try to compile, or is it just the IDE showing it?

Comment: @ManosNikolaidis `-Werror` is a red herring, it doesn't activate any extra warnings, it only makes all warnings behave like errors.

Comment: @FUZxxl the full command I used was `gcc -W -Wall -m64   -c -g -Werror -std=c11 -MMD -MP -MF`. Still no complains (gcc 4.8.3)

Comment: @ManosNikolaidis Try `-Weverything`.

Comment: @FUZxxl `gcc` doesn't recognize `-Weverything`

Comment: @ManosNikolaidis Sorry, `-Weverything` is for clang, I don't know the corresponding gcc flag.

Comment: The thing I hate about that Visual Studio warning is that it assumes you never meant to do it. `if` with a constant expression is actually quite useful sometimes.

Answer (score 4):

I just tried it on CLANG with extended warning turned on and received the following warning:

[image]

Referring to (oddly enough) only the the first of the two lines in the switch that will never be executed:

```
   case 1: printf("1");
```

Comment: It's clear why this happens: `case` labels are just labels and the whole block in the switch is never going to be executed so `clang` only warns about the block, not every statement in it.

Comment: @FUZxxl - Sure.  That would make sense, except that the `default` case statement is executed.

Answer (score 3):

From the [C 2011 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):

> **5.1.1.3 Diagnostics**
> 1     A conforming implementation shall produce at least one diagnostic message (identified in
> an implementation-defined manner) if a preprocessing translation unit or translation unit
> contains a violation of any syntax rule or constraint, even if the behavior is also explicitly
> specified as undefined or implementation-defined. **Diagnostic messages need not be
> produced in other circumstances.**<sup>9)</sup>
>
> ---
>
> <sup>9) The intent is that an implementation should identify the nature of, and where possible localize, each
> violation. Of course, an implementation is free to produce any number of diagnostics as long as a
> valid program is still correctly translated. It may also successfully translate an invalid program.</sup>

Emphasis added.

So, a diagnostic is required if using a constant expression in a `switch` or `if` control expression is a constraint violation...

> **6.8.4.1 The `if` statement**
> **Constraints**
> 1     The controlling expression of an `if` statement shall have scalar type.
> ...
> **6.8.4.2 The `switch` statement**
> **Constraints**
> 1  The controlling expression of a `switch` statement shall have integer type.
> 2     If a `switch` statement has an associated `case` or `default` label within the scope of an
> identifier with a variably modified type, the entire `switch` statement shall be within the
> scope of that identifier.<sup>154)</sup>
> 3     The expression of each `case` label shall be an integer constant expression and no two of
> the case constant expressions in the same `switch` statement shall have the same value
> after conversion. There may be at most one `default` label in a switch statement.
> (Any enclosed `switch` statement may have a `default` label or `case` constant
> expressions with values that duplicate `case` constant expressions in the enclosing
> `switch` statement.)
>
> ---
>
> <sup>154) That is, the declaration either precedes the `switch` statement, or it follows the last `case` or
> `default` label associated with the `switch` that is in the block containing the declaration.</sup>

...which it isn't.

This is basically a quality of implementation issue; the implementation *may* issue a diagnostic for using a constant expression in an `if` or `switch` statement, but it doesn't have to.  `if( 0 )` and `switch( 0 )` may strike most of us as being hinky, but the implementation is not required to issue any diagnostics over them.

Comment: This answer states the obvious - not useful.

Comment: @anatolyg: which part is "obvious" - that the compiler need not issue a diagnostic for anything that isn't a constraint violation, or that using a constant expression in a `switch` or `if` statement isn't a constraint violation?

Comment: Both (I got this impression after reading comments; maybe the question itself doesn't make it obvious).

Comment: @anatolyg - What a funny statement to make.  The level to which something is _obvious_ is typically directly proportional to the level of expertise of the person making the observation.  If the content of this answer were really obvious to the majority of the people using Stackoverflow, there would be no need for Stackoverflow.  The conclusion statement (_quality of implementation issue_), by the way, sums it up nicely.

Answer (score 1):

I just tried `clang -Weverything`: it complains about `argc` and `argv` not being used, but stays silent about `switch(0)`, just like `gcc`.

While it is not mandatory for the compiler to issue a diagnostic, a warning might help if the error is a typo.  Try this one for example:

```
int test(int l) {
    switch (1) {
    case 0: return 0;
    case 1: return 1;
    default: return -1;
}
```

You should file a bug on both projects.

EDIT: `clang` seems to have fixed this recently, unlike what ryyker shows in his response, `-Wunreachable-code` does not complain on my laptop. I might have an older version.

Answer (score 1):

To get the warning in Visual Studio 2013 you need:

1. right click on the project --> properties
2. C/C++ in the section General set Warning level to ALL

The warning is only for the if statement because the switch is a block.

[image]

Comment: So what's the point of this answer? `if (0)` yields a warning in VS2012 too, I know that. With warning level 4. I already wrote that in the question.